# Macro to map "items" to their type parameterized "containers" -- large compiler error

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Suppose I have a trait for "items" and another trait for "containers" of those items:

```
sealed trait Item
case class Marble() extends Item
case class Book() extends Item

sealed trait Container[Item]
case object Pouch extends Container[Marble]
case object Shelf extends Container[Book]
```

Using the type information above, I'd like to construct a map like so via a macro and some runtime reflection:

```
// Map(classOf[Marble] -> Pouch, classOf[Book] -> Shelf)
val itemToContainer = typeParamMap[Container[_], Item](Pouch, Shelf)
```

Here's my attempt, which compiles fine, and works in an intermediate form that just returns the list of TypeTags:

```
object Macros {
  def getTag[T](implicit ttag: ru.TypeTag[T]) = ttag

  def getBaseParam(child: ru.Type, base: ru.Symbol, paramBase: ru.Symbol) =
    child.baseType(base)
      .find(_.baseClasses.contains(paramBase))
      .get
      .typeSymbol
      .asClass // TODO how to get java.lang.Class from here?

  def typeParamMapImpl[B, P](c: Context)(children: c.Expr[B]*)(baseTag: c.Expr[ru.WeakTypeTag[B]], paramTag: c.Expr[ru.WeakTypeTag[P]]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val getTagTree = Select(Ident(newTermName("Macros")), "getTag")
    val typeTags = c.Expr[List[ru.TypeTag[_]]](Apply(reify(List).tree, children.map( t =>
      c.Expr(TypeApply(getTagTree, List(t.tree))).tree
    ).toList))

    reify {
      typeTags.splice.map { child =>
        getBaseParam(child.tpe, baseTag.splice.tpe.typeSymbol, paramTag.splice.tpe.typeSymbol) -> child.tpe
      }.toMap
    }
  }

  def typeParamMap[B, P](children: B*)(implicit baseTag: ru.WeakTypeTag[B], paramTag: ru.WeakTypeTag[P]) = macro Macros.typeParamMapImpl[B, P]
}
```

However when I try to compile with an invocation of this, I get a huge compiler error: https://gist.github.com/4647812

Can anyone spot the problem, or suggest a better way of going about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you intend this to be used, but it's likely that a type class-based solution (like [this](https://gist.github.com/4651653), for example) would be both more idiomatic and more type safe.